# Need advice after UK visit visa refusal due to a technical issue

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I had recently applied for a UK visit visa from Pakistan along with my mother to visit my aunt. My visa got refused because they said that I had not submitted my bank statement (which I did).

I even sent a pre action protocol letter with the PDF from VFS that contained the list of documents I had attached. They outrightly denied that they had received the bank statement.

Now I have a few questions:

1. I received Australia visa after my UK refusal so should I reapply
   right now or after I come back from Australia? Currently I have only
   traveled to Dubai and Turkey.
2. If I am to reapply, should I apply as a lone traveler or should I
   mention my aunt? (considering that family ties in UK might count as
   a negative)
3. Is there any other way apart from reapplying/Judicial review to fix
   this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> I received Australia visa after my UK refusal so should I reapply right now or after I come back from Australia? Currently I have only traveled to Dubai and Turkey.

Are you planning to go to the UK before Australia? If not - apply after you're back, you'll show that you've returned home from a visit to a similar country before.

> If I am to reapply, should I apply as a lone traveler or should I mention my aunt? (considering that family ties in UK might count as a negative)

Lying is worse. They already know that you planned to visit your aunt.

> Is there any other way apart from reapplying/Judicial review to fix this issue?

Unlikely. How important this trip was for you? If it's not critical - just try again next time you have time to travel.

Comment: I don't have any particular itinerary right now so I can follow your advice and travel to Australia first. Thanks!